# getting error Call to a member function hasRole() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

i managed to make roles in my app but when i try to loginIn it told some error in loginController
this my code  in loginController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectTo()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
        $this->redirectTo = route('admin.index');
    } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('user') && Auth::user()->isBanned()) {
        Auth::logout();
        $this->redirectTo = route('contact');
    } else {
        $this->redirectTo = route('post.index');
    }

    return $this->redirectTo;
}
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` is null; are you authenticated?

Comment: in page login the error "Call to a member function hasRole() on null"

Comment: @yolo what is supposed to return `Auth::user()` is you are not logged??

Comment: You're trying to use this code before you're authenticated. `Auth::user()` is `null` unless you have logged. Refactor your code so you don't use this before logging in.

Comment: ath::user()->hasrole() suppose to check if the authenticated user has role admin or user

Comment: there isn't an authenticated user for the current default guard, so its returning `null` ... :-)

Comment: how can i redirect admin/user to his specific route ?

Comment: do you have a custom `login` method on this controller? is this a default one besides this `redirectTo` method? we need to see what you are doing since there is no authenticated user at the moment, hence why you are getting a `null`

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this and it worked well for me.

```
if(\Auth::check() && $request->user()->authorizeRoles($role) != null){``
    if (!$request->user()->authorizeRoles($role)) {
        return redirect('/index');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/login');`
```